# Wrong prompt when editing questions with disallowed tag

Tags: bug, tags, editing

When editing a question with tag that isn't allowed, the message below is shown which incorrectly uses 'Your answer' instead of 'Your edit':

> Oops! Your **answer** couldn't be submitted because:
>
> The 'install' tag is not allowed